# No Mate layouts?

Tags: server, 18.04, themes, mate, layout

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS installed, with the Mate Desktop (not Ubuntu: Mate Edition, keep in mind)

and i cant choose ANY mate layouts in the Mate-Tweaks applet. the only available one is Gnome2

in the layouts folder it has all the themes and layouts that mate ships with, how can i select these if they arent showing in the control panel?

Comment: My guess from your wording is you didn't install `ubuntu-mate-desktop` (which installs everything that comes with Ubuntu Mate https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-mate-desktop), thus didn't get all packages needed for theming.  Next guess is if you're using a server, they usually have limited graphic cards (esp. with regards memory) some features are disabled because of limited memory in your graphics card.

Comment: well i think it was installed.  it has pretty much everything. it even has all the layouts, i just cant choose any of them

Comment: The link I provided tells you what you should have installed (all dependencies). To tweak you also need many of the recommends; and your apt logs will remind you what you installed (if you forget), though I'd probably `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop` to see what it'll ask permission to install, for a list of what you didn't install and could have missing. You can answer 'n' to the apt install & not install anything; and if it wants to install nothing then you have everything and this idea is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The MATE Tweak [looks for panel layouts](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-tweak/blob/bionic/mate-tweak#L663) into the `/usr/share/mate-panel/layouts/` directory.

The search on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS gives the following packages:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S /usr/share/mate-panel/layouts/
> ubuntu-mate-default-settings, mate-panel: /usr/share/mate-panel/layouts
> ```

So you need to have installed two packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-default-settings mate-panel
```

but to have more reproducible results I can recommend to install `ubuntu-mate-desktop` *task* with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

and then reboot.